# Tengo que crear un programa que diga la palabra más repetida en un archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Tengo esto, he intentado contar el numero de palabras pero no sé como seguir y decir cual es la palabra más repetida.

```
import os 

nombre=input('escribe el nombre del archivo:')

if (os.path.exists(nombre) ):
    fin=open(nombre,'r')

    sumatotal=0
    lineas=fin.readlines()
    for palabra in lineas:
        palabra=palabra[:-1]
        total+=palabra
    fin.close()

    print(total)

else:
    print('no se ha podido encontrar el archivo')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución basada en tu código.

Para contar las ocurrencias de cada palabra usaremos un diccionario llamado `indice`, indexado por la palabra. El valor asociado es el número de apareciones en el texto.

En lugar de usar un `dict` común y corriente, usaremos un `defaultdict`, que tiene la gracia de inicializar automáticamente las llaves que no existen, lo que simplifica la vida.

En este caso, queremos un diccionario con valores enteros (automáticamente inicializados en cero), por lo que decimos:

```
indice = defaultdict(int)
```

Abrimos el archivo y leemos linea por linea. Cada linea la dividimos en palabras usando `split`, incrementando los contadores en el diccionario `indice`.

Una vez terminado el proceso, se calcula la palabra más frecuente. Para eso se usa la función `max`. Esta función aplicada sin más devuelve la máxima llave en orden alfabético. Pero, con el parámetro opcional `key=` podemos darle otro criterio de ordenación:

```
mas_repetida = max(indice, key=indice.get)
```

Lo que logra calcular el máximo por el valor asociado a la palabra.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

nombre=input('escribe el nombre del archivo:')

if (os.path.exists(nombre) ):
    fin=open(nombre,'r')
    indice = defaultdict(int)
    for linea in fin:
        for palabra in linea.split():
            indice[palabra] += 1
    fin.close()
    mas_repetida = max(indice, key=indice.get)
    print(f"La palabra mas repetida es \"{mas_repetida}\", con {index[mas_repetida]} menciones")
else:
    print('no se ha podido encontrar el archivo')
```